# How to update certain records (or a range of records) in specific column of a table in SQL Server using While Loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table with columns `Id` and `TransactionNo`.

The `Id` column has a range of ids starting from 1 to 3000.

What I need to do is to update the `TransactionNo` column for the id's ranging from 1000 to 2000.

In other words, `TransactionNo` must be updated only for `Id` in a range of 1000 to 2000 incrementing by one (++1) for each `Id` upwards.

Since it is a tedious job, I am looking for a while loop solution to update all `TransactionNo` in this range of Ids.

Comment: Post the sample data and expected output

Comment: What value you want to update in TransactionId column?

Comment: Consider "TransactionNo" =10000 for "Id" = 1000.
"TransactionNo" must be incremented by one as Id increases.

Answer (score 2):

In case there are gaps in your `id` sequence and you want a continuous sequence for your generated column you could use `row_number()` like shown here:

```
update t set trn=rn from
  (select trn,row_number()
   over (order by id) rn
   from t1
   where id>=1000 and id<=2000) t
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d0630ac07341f98a3b8eee00f40b9c6b)

Answer (score 1):

try like below

```
update table
 set TransactionNo=id-1000
  where id>1000 and id<=2000
```

[Demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5fec9eb96b6debcadea29ff1a394c1eb)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for following query.

```
UPDATE table 
SET    transactionno = transactionno + 1 
WHERE  id >= 1000 
       AND id <= 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
update tablename
set transactionno = (select transactionno from tablename where id = 1000) + id - 1000
where id > 1000 and id <= 2000
```

it keeps the `transactionno` of `id = 1000` and increments the rest by 1 from `id = 1001` to `id = 2000`.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=cc0fc6f9f7770768c760f609b63f135a)
Or with a CTE:

```
with cte as (
  select transactionno from tablename where id = 1000
)
update tablename
set transactionno = (select transactionno from cte) + id - 1000
where id > 1000 and id <= 2000
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=e482ef87c70a432a5c4b726865d8371f)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @startID = 1000
while(@startID <= 2000)
begin
   update table set TransactionNo = value where Id = @startID;
   set @StartID += 1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET TransactionNo = Id
WHERE Id BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000
```

*Note:* you can change this assignment statement (i.e. `= Id`) with whatever the value you want.